# data.table: New boolean column based on existence of value in other columns

Tags: r, data.table

Say that I have a `data.table` with numerical values, and I want a new column that is `TRUE`if a certain numeric value exists in specific other columns, and `FALSE` if it doesn't. So if I have this table:

```
    a   b   c
1   23  12  34
2   12  56  43
3   11  12  14
4   13  23  6
5   13  15  4
6   12  23  56
7   76  23  1
8   2   9   22
9   5   21  12
10  12  65  31
```

and I want a column that tells me which rows have `12` in columns `a` or `c`, i.e. the result would be

```
    a   b   c   ac_12
1   23  12  34  FALSE
2   12  56  43  TRUE
3   11  12  14  FALSE
4   13  23  6   FALSE
5   13  15  4   FALSE
6   12  23  56  TRUE
7   76  23  1   FALSE
8   2   9   22  FALSE
9   5   21  12  TRUE
10  12  65  31  TRUE
```

I have tried doing something like

```
val <- 12
cols <- c("a", "c")
dt[, ac_12 := lapply(.SD, function(x) val %in% x), .SDcols = cols]
```

but that did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your data is called `dt`, `dt[, ac_12 := a == 12 | c == 12]` will do, I think.

Comment: You can do it step by step, if you feel more comfortable: First, assign `FALSE` to your new column: `dt[, ac_12 := FALSE]`. Then filter the cases of interest and assign `TRUE` to the column: `ac[a == 12 | c == 12, ac_12 := TRUE]`. Not sleek code, but if it's easier for you, then it's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
dat[, ac_12 := rowSums(do.call(cbind, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, val))) > 0, .SDcols = cols ]
#      a  b  c ac_12
#  1: 23 12 34 FALSE
#  2: 12 56 43  TRUE
#  3: 11 12 14 FALSE
#  4: 13 23  6 FALSE
#  5: 13 15  4 FALSE
#  6: 12 23 56  TRUE
#  7: 76 23  1 FALSE
#  8:  2  9 22 FALSE
#  9:  5 21 12  TRUE
# 10: 12 65 31  TRUE
```

To see what's going on, let's start with the inner-most (hard-coding the arguments just for this walk-through):

```r
lapply(dat[,c('a','c')], `%in%`, val)
# $a
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# $c
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

do.call(cbind, lapply(dat[,c('a','c')], `%in%`, val))
#           a     c
#  [1,] FALSE FALSE
#  [2,]  TRUE FALSE
#  [3,] FALSE FALSE
#  [4,] FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE FALSE
#  [6,]  TRUE FALSE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE  TRUE
# [10,]  TRUE FALSE

rowSums(do.call(cbind, lapply(dat[,c('a','c')], `%in%`, val)))
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
```